Rational function with radicals that has only removable singularities, can be rewritten such that the denominator is nonzero?
For polynomials $P(x),Q(x)$, if zeros of $Q(x)$ all are removable singularities of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ then we can cancel the common factors of $P(x),Q(x)$ to get a new function $\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}$ such that $Q_1(x)$ is nonzero everywhere.
To generalize this, I want to ask the following question:

Let $P,Q$ be two functions on a closed set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that is a composition of radicals and polynomials.
If zeros of $Q(x)$ all are removable singularities of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$,
then this continuous function can be written as $\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}$ for two functions $P_1,Q_1$ on $S$ that is a composition of radicals and polynomials, such that the denominator $Q_1(x)$ is nonzero on $S$.

Similar: Zero set of nested radicals

Example
$P(x)=x-3,Q(x)=x-\sqrt{x+6}$ are defined on $S=[-6,+\infty)$
The only zero of $Q(x)$ is $x=3$.
$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is bounded near $3$ [The limit is $\frac56$].
And there exist functions $P_1(x)=2+\sqrt{6+x},Q_1(x)=3+\sqrt{6+x}$ defined on $S$ such that
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}$$
and $Q_1(x)\ne0$ on $S$.

By multiplying "conjugates" of $P(x),Q(x)$ and canceling the root of $Q(x)$, we can find $P_2(x),Q_2(x)$ such that
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_2(x)}{Q_2(x)}$$
and $Q,Q_2$ don't have common roots. Then we have a family of $P_1,Q_1$:
$$P_1(x)=a(x)P(x)+b(x)P_2(x)\\Q_1(x)=a(x)Q(x)+b(x)Q_2(x)$$
for any polynomials $a(x),b(x)$, satisfy
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}$$
Let $a(x)$ have same roots as $Q(x)$, and have same sign as $Q(x)$ on $S$, then $a(x)Q(x)>0$ on $S$ except at roots of $Q(x)$.
Let $b(x)$ have same roots as $Q_1(x)$, and have same sign as $Q_1(x)$ on $S$, then $b(x)Q_1(x)>0$ on $S$ except at roots of $Q_1(x)$.
then $Q_1=a(x)Q(x)+b(x)Q_2(x)>0$ on $S$.
Example
$$P(x)=47x-21\\
Q(x)=\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}+\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}+2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42$$are defined on $S=[0,+\infty)$.
The only zero of $Q(x)$ is $x=\frac{21}{47}$.
$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is bounded near $x=\frac{21}{47}$ (WA calculation of the limit).
By multiplying $Q$ by its $7$ conjugutes to form a polynomial and canceling the common root $21/47$ with $P$, I get
$$P_2=\left(\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}+\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}-2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right) \left(\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}-\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}+2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right) \left(\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}-\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}-2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right) \left(-\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}+\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}+2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right) \left(-\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}+\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}-2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right) \left(-\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}-\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}+2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right) \left(-\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x (x+7)}-\sqrt{14} \sqrt{x (x+15)}-2 \sqrt{21} \sqrt{x (x+20)}-42\right)$$
$$Q_2=256 (x+21)^3 (5 x-21) \left(235 x^3+8211 x^2-18963 x+9261\right)$$
such that
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_2(x)}{Q_2(x)}$$
and $Q,Q_2$ don't have common roots. Then we have a family of $P_1,Q_1$:
$$P_1(x)=a(x)P(x)+b(x)P_2(x)\\Q_1(x)=a(x)Q(x)+b(x)Q_2(x)$$
for any polynomials $a(x),b(x)$, satisfy
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}$$
Let $a(x)=47x-21$, so that $a(x)Q(x)=\left(47x-21\right)\left(\sqrt{6}\sqrt{x(x+7)}+\sqrt{14}\sqrt{x(x+15)}+2\sqrt{21}\sqrt{x(x+20)}-42\right)$ is positive on $S$ except at roots of $Q(x)$.
Let $b(x)=(5x-21)\left(235x^{3}+8211x^{2}-18963x+9261\right)$, so that $b(x)Q_1(x)=(x+21)^{3}(5x-21)^{2}\left(235x^{3}+8211x^{2}-18963x+9261\right)^{2}$ is positive on $S$ except at roots of $Q_1(x)$.
Then $Q_1(x)=a(x)Q(x)+b(x)Q_2(x)$ is positive on $S$.
By Desmos I verified $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)}$ and $Q_1(x)>0$ on $S=[0,+\infty)$.

